# what is status of EG25011a, when it is going to expire?

Tags: linaglitin, egypt

What is status of EG25011a, when it is going to expire IN EGYPT.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer so this is not legal advice. [The cited Egyptian patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/EG25011A/en?oq=EG25011a) claims priority to two German applications filed on 2002-08-21 and 2003-03-20. Normally one would expect a granted patent to expire 20 years from its priority date. This would lead me to expect the patent to be expired. There is the possibility of patent term extensions (at least in the US) so I would check the status with someone more experienced with international patents than I am. Also, there is the potential for related patents that are still in force.

Answer (score 0):

this patent expired in 2023-08-19 in Egypt. (Source Orbit Intelligence)
But this patent also has many family patents, some  of them are still active in few countries. But if you want to use/sell this patent in Egypt, then you don't have to worry about infringing this patent, as it is expired in Egypt.